# Python multiple choice game that doesn't end after one choice

Tags: python

```
import random
from random import randint

number = randint(1, 500)
guess = input("The computer has chosen a random number. Guess the number: ")
guess = int(guess)

while guess == number:
    print("Congrats, you have won")
    break

if guess > number:
    print("Lower")

if guess < number:
    print("Higher")
```

This code only allows the user to input one guess and then the program ends. Can someone help me fix this

Comment: Hint: There is no point in a `while` loop that always `break`s.

Comment: ^ notice how most of the answers to that question have `while True` in them

Comment: Better to use the condition guess != number for the while loop... While true is horrible to read

Answer (score 2):

You should think about your loop condition.

- When do you want to repeat? This is the loop condition

  - When the guess is *not* correct. `guess != number`
- What do you want to repeat? Put these *inside* the loop

  - Asking for a guess `guess = int(input("Your guess: "))`
  - Printing if it's higher or lower `if guess >` or `< number: ...`
- What *don't* you want to repeat?

  - You need this *before* the loop

    - Deciding the correct number.
    - Setting the initial guess so the loop is entered once
  - You need this *after* the loop

    - Printing the `"correct!"` message, because you only exit the loop once the guess is correct

So we have:

```
number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = 0

while guess != number:
    guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
    if guess > number:
       print("Lower")
    elif guess < number:
       print("Higher")

print("Correct!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your `while` loop is useless as once you are in it you break immediately. The rest of the code is not in a loop.

You should rather have an infinite loop with all your code, and break when there is a match:

```
from random import randint

number = randint(1, 500)

while True:                    # infinite loop
    guess = input("The computer has chosen a random number. Guess the number: ")
    guess = int(guess)         # warning, this will raise an error if
                               # the user inputs something else that digits

    if guess == number:        # condition is met, we're done
        print("Congrats, you have won")
        break

    elif guess > number:       # test if number is lower
        print("Lower")

    else:                      # no need to test again, is is necessarily  higher
        print("Higher")
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi true, small oversight ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You must take input in the loop, because the value for each step has to be updated .

```
from random import randint


number = randint(1, 500)

while True:
    guess = input("The computer has chosen a random number. Guess the number: ")
    guess = int(guess)
    
    
    if guess == number:
        print("Congrats, you have won")
        break

    if guess > number:
        print("Lower")

    if guess < number:
        print("Higher")
```